# Type-mismatch but no apparent type mismatches with Dim or usage

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, type-mismatch

This For-Loop carries out exactly what I want it to do but then it seems to have trouble exiting  the loop and continuing on to more code below. Not understanding why it is getting type mismatch

I am using this same exact block of code to do more copy and paste from different sources to a master sheet for my records and it works perfectly. For some reason, this particular one is different and there is no apparent reason because i literally have just copied and pasted the code and changed the worksheet names in later blocks

```
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
b = 2

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Tour Info")).Name = "Optional Excursions"
Workbooks("Tour Code Optionals").Worksheets("2019 Internal Descriptions").Range("A1:Z1").Copy
Workbooks("AAB").Worksheets("Optional Excursions").Range("A1:Z1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks("AAB").Worksheets("Optional Excursions").Range("A1:Z1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
For a = 2 To 422
    If InStr(Workbooks("Tour Code Optionals").Worksheets("2019 Internal Descriptions").Range("C" & a), Workbooks("AAB").Worksheets("Tour Info").Range("A1")) > 0 Then
    Workbooks("Tour Code Optionals").Worksheets("2019 Internal Descriptions").Range("A" & a, "Z" & a).Copy
    Workbooks("AAB").Worksheets("Optional Excursions").Range("A" & b, "Z" & b).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Workbooks("AAB").Worksheets("Optional Excursions").Range("A" & b, "Z" & b).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    b = b + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That suggests there is something different about the worksheet you are trying to copy from.

Comment: My guess is that you have errors in the worksheet

Comment: Somewhere in Workbooks("Tour Code Optionals").Worksheets("2019 Internal Descriptions").Range("C" & a) from a = 2 to 422 there's a cell with no text in it. It's either empty or an error value